# When we can't use “can” instead of “be able to”?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

> I had to think about it for a while, but finally I **was able to** solve this problem.

Why can't I use "could" instead of "was able to" in this sentence?

Comment: I think you could use _could_ there, but because _could_ has a number of other meanings, it might be ambiguous, and so native speakers tend to avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can vs. Will be able to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191061/can-vs-will-be-able-to)

Answer (score 1):

As you state, there is only a very fine difference in connotation between "can/could" and "able to".

The difference might be illustrated with these two sentences:

"Beth can apply for the grant," could mean:

1. Someone asked, "How can she pay for the research? and this answer suggests one possible way to raise funds -- it does not imply she necessarily qualifies or has permission.
2. Someone asked, "Does she qualify for funding?" and this answer states the she *does* have permission -- with emphasis on *can*.

On the other hand, "Beth is able to apply for the grant," is more likely to have the second connotation, i.e., of *permission*.

It depends on context, and in most cases, they'd be interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that "was able to X" has (at least) two possible meanings: "had the ability to X" and "successfully did X". One is about the ability, and the other about actually doing it.

To make it clearer, let's simplify the sentence, and put it in the present simple:

> I **can** run a marathon.

Here, the word "can" only means "*have the ability to*". It doesn't mean having ever done it.

This meaning of "*have the ability to*" is the same in the past:

> When I was was 20, I could run marathons.

This only means "I **had the ability to** run marathons. It doesn't mean I ever did.

On the other hand, "was able to" has (at least) two functions: had an ability in the past, OR successfully did something in the past. So this sentence is ambiguous:

> When I was 20, I was able to run a marathon.

It could mean I had the ability ("could"), or it could mean I actually did it.

The word "finally" makes it clear which function it has:

> I was finally able to run a marathon when I was 20.

This makes it 100% clear that I completed a marathon when I was 20.

So, in your example sentence, the intent is clearly that the speaker succeeded in solving this problem. This means "was able to" is correct.

It's worth noting that many native speakers might use "could", but it's marked and sounds uneducated or child-like. An editor would correct it to "was able to" or something similar.